# Unable to remove all checked objects in one time

Tags: angularjs

I am learning to use an Angular. I tried to remove checked objects from array but all of them weren't removed in one time. Here is my code,

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="myController">
    [<a href="" ng-click="remove()">remove</a>]
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.checked"/>
            {{user.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>  
  </div> 

  <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){

      $scope.users = [
          {name:'John Smith', checked: false}, 
          {name: 'John Doe', checked: false}, 
          {name: 'Jane Doe', checked: false}, 
          {name:'Marry Jane', checked: false}        
      ]; 

      $scope.remove = function(){
          $scope.users.forEach(function(user){
              if(user.checked){
                  var index = $scope.users.indexOf(user);
                  $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
              }
          });
      };      

    });
  </script>
</body>
```

*note http://plnkr.co/edit/uBD74w5ywiadlPcML4Cz?p=preview

I didn't know what's wrong in the code. I really need help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a filter : http://plnkr.co/edit/yguJrF2fDRYkS7PcfiXT?p=preview

```
$scope.remove = function(){
  $scope.users = $filter('filter')($scope.users, {checked : false});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As you remove items from users array, array changes and `forEach` loop does not work as you expected; because your original array changes after each remove operation.

Using filter function of arrays would do your work correctly.

```
$scope.remove = function(){
    $scope.users = $scope.users.filter(function(user){
      return !user.checked;
    });
};
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gMjyC8FqOsIsLOwMrGlB?p=preview)

Comment: Please note that this answer has browser requirements: FF 1.5 and IE 9

Answer (score 0):

You can remove by reduce like this:

```
$scope.remove = function(){
    $scope.users  = $scope.users.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){
     if(!currentValue.checked){
        previousValue.push(currentValue);
     }
     return previousValue;
  },[]);
};
```